# Combine two queries in to one

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to sql I just want to ask for advice my query is working fine it gives me my desired output but I wanted to make it in one query only I want to combine my delete query to the select query. I would really appreciate anyone can teach me how to do it

```
Delete from tblexample where RStatus = 'Done';
SELECT t3.RStatus,t1.Name,t2.gender,t1.Rnum,t1.NB,t1.fN
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON (t1.fN = t2.fln)

LEFT JOIN (

   select * from tblexample t3   
) AS t3  ON  t1.NB = t3.NB  where t3.RStatus is null
```

Like if possible I want to delete firs before I left join the tblexample

Comment: You can't. But you can wrap them up in a transaction

Comment: According to my understanding of SQL Concepts it is not possible to combine DML and select statements..

Comment: how can I wrap them in transaction?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: like if possible delete first then select?

Comment: This is order of execution. As it is written right now it will first delete and then select.

Comment: yes delete first then left join it

Comment: you can combine it as `delete ... from ... where ('value' in select...)`

Comment: Please refer to some external resources to get better undestanding of SQL basics. You can't combine these two statements into one. You can execute both in order. If you need to wrap them up within a transaction read about transactions, but this will still work the same as without transaction, as there is only one DML statement.

Comment: If this is about first deleting, then selecting what's still there? Then you already have that. If you run them in that order then the select will only run after the delete statement finished.